# Return a single value from a nested each block, trying to use 'return'

Tags: ruby

```
def get_type
  x = [{:type=>'A', :patterns=>['foo.*']}, {:type=>'B', :patterns=>['bar.*']}]

  name = 'foo.txt'

  result = x.each { |item|
    item[:patterns].each { |regex|
      puts "Checking #{regex} against #{name}"
      if !name.match(regex).nil?
        puts "Found match: #{item[:type]}"
        return item[:type]
      end
    }
  }
end

result = get_type
puts "result: #{result}"
```

Expected output:

```
Checking foo.* against foo.txt
Found match: A
result: A
```

However, all I see is:

```
Checking foo.* against foo.txt
Found match: A
```

My current work around is this:

```
def get_type
  x = [{:type=>'A', :patterns=>['foo.*']}, {:type=>'B', :patterns=>['bar.*']}]

  name = 'foo.txt'

  result = []
  x.each { |item|
    item[:patterns].each { |regex|
      puts "Checking #{regex} against #{name}"
      if !name.match(regex).nil?
        puts "Found match: #{item[:type]}"
        result << item[:type]
      end
    }
  }
  result[0] unless result.empty?
end
```

Why doesn't the first approach work? or maybe it is 'working', I just don't understand why I'm not getting what I'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me. Are you actually invoking it with

```
result = get_type puts "result: #{result}"
```

? Because that shouldn't work at all, though I'm assuming there's a linefeed that got eaten when you posted this.

Comment: You're right. I had some other typo. What I did find out is if there is no match then "result" will be set equal to the 'x' array. That's a condition I need to watch for.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest a refactor? your code looks kind of clunky because you are using `each` loops (imperative) when you in fact need a `map`+`first` (functional). As Ruby enumerables are not lazy this would be inefficient, so people usually build the abstraction `Enumerable#map_detect` (or `find_yield`, or `find_first`, or `map_first`):

```
def get_type_using_map_detect(name)
  xs = [{:type => 'A', :patterns => ['foo.*']}, {:type => 'B', :patterns => ['bar.*']}]
  xs.map_detect do |item|
    item[:patterns].map_detect do |regex|
      item[:type] if name.match(regex)
    end
  end
end
```

This is a possible implementation of the method:

```
module Enumerable
  # Like Enumerable#map but return only the first non-nil value
  def map_detect
    self.each do |item|
      if result = (yield item)
        return result
      end
    end
    nil
  end
end
```